# How to put custom application logs in s3 bucket from AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I have custom application/service for AWS EMR that I'm installing from bootstrap action on all nodes. My I want to put logs file of that application in same s3 bucket that I'm using for emr-logs.

Can anyone suggest me where I have to configure my log path in logpusher to get logs in s3 bucket in fixed interval same as a hadoop application.

Answer (score 1):

you can configure it in /etc/logpusher/hadoop.config and restart the logpusher on all nodes